# Why is MassTransit using ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor for message deserialization?

Tags: masstransit

I'm trying to incorporate MassTransit in a project that also uses NHibernate. NHibernate requires me to have at least a default constructor with protected internal visibility.

I run into the following problem. Messages can be published without any problem, however the handlers receive the message objects with uninitialized members. After some period of debugging and inspection of the MassTransit sources I found out that this is caused by the fact that MassTransit uses the setting ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor during deserialization, which causes my protected internal default constructor to be called instead of the parametrized constructor. I managed to reproduce this behavior, see code below.

What's the reason behind MassTransit's use of AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor, and is there any way to change this behavior?

```cs
class Program
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        private readonly string _someString;

        public string SomeString {
            get { return _someString; }
        }

        public TestClass(string someString)
        {
            _someString = someString;
        }

        protected internal TestClass()
        {
            _someString = "uninitialized";
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new TestClass("Hello World");

        var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor,
                    ContractResolver = new ... // MassTransit contract resolver that includes private setters
                };


        string serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, serializerSettings);

        var deserializedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(serializedObject, serializerSettings);

        // deserializedObj.SomeString == "uninitialized"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages shouldn't have any logic in them at all. Messages are contracts. Any logic in them will only end up bitting you again and again. :( We will always use a default, no parameter, constructor. If there isn't one we won't deserialize your message.

We suggest that you alway consume interfaces instead of concrete types to help enforce the removal of logic from message types. But if you *really* want to have this behaviour you'll need to write your own serializer.

If you want to discuss further, I suggest you join the mailing list: groups.google.com/group/masstransit-discuss.

Comment: The reason I'm using this read only private backing field for the public property is that it is my preferred (puristic) way of defining an immutable object.

Comment: Sure. Translate the message to a domain object that has whatever logic is needed. Messages should just be property bags, nothing else. You have the reasoning, and there's no way to change this with the default serializers.